Mystery about piano songs
I have a 2003 Readers Digest Merry Christmas song book.  Every song is written with smaller notes to the right of the larger notes.
What is this called?

Please post an image. There's not enough information here to provide an answer.

Is it like https://music.stackexchange.com/q/118128/78419 or https://music.stackexchange.com/q/95502/78419?

Have searched and searched, but cannot find what the notes are called. Unusual, as we do like to label everything!

Knowing Reader's Digest music books?
When a song has more two stanzas, they displayed the alternate notes in a different size, so that it's easier to keep track.
Especially when the entire song is displayed on one flat, open paged, hard-bound book like that.

Thanks for answering, but if that's the case, then this question is a duplicate of the other two and it would be better to close it.
